# How to move to next route when user confirms in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have implemented a custom confirm box alert using a jquery plugin. My requirement is that when the user confirms his option (i.e he clicks on the yes button in the confirm box) he should be going to the route that he has chosen. If he clicks no then he should remain on the same page.

```
  /*location change logic*/
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, nextUrl) {

    if (checkAllInputFields()) {

        event.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("User confirmed dialog");
                $location.path(newUrl);  //this does not work
               //i get the console but the user does not go to the selected route
            } else {

                console.log("User declined dialog");
            }
        });

    }
});
```

For some reason, even when the user clicks the Ok button in the confirm box he is not redirected to the route he has chosen.

Can someone help resolve this issue?

Comment: are you looking for `$location.path('/newValue')` ?

Comment: `For some reason` is quite simple, you prevented default. What is `checkAllInputFields` ? Doesn't appear to be scope item. Create a demo

Comment: no. I added that but still it does not work. check my updated code

Comment: @charlietfl: if I dont prevent default then it navigates to the new page and shows the alert over there...which does not make sense. the alert should come on the same page where the form exists

Comment: right, but you will need to parse new url now and set the path, but you will also have an infinite loop without changing the variable `checkAllInputFields`

Comment: @charlietfl: checkInputFields() returns true or false based on whether any inputs in the form are entered (i.e if any input box has  value it will return true else it will return false)

Comment: right, but it won't change so if you call `$location.path()` it will still trigger `$locationChangeStart` and bootbox will fire again. Also `newUrl` is full url not a path

Comment: @charlietfl: Yes agreed. Is there a better solution then? I am stuck as of now.

Comment: depends on how app works ...can you use a click event? Or are there too many ways for user to change routes? Can add another condition and change a variable inside the confirm. Also should use `$apply` inside callback. Where's the demo?

Comment: @charlietfl: click event for what? the confirm box button?.  There are many ways for user to change the route. check the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/8duv7yoj/

Comment: demo isn't of much value since no ng-view , suggest copy one from elesewhere, don't need bootbox, can use native confirm

Comment: Ok i will create the ng-view. However, I can't use the native confirm since it shows a ugly title saying "page at localhost ....". I need a custom confirm box

Comment: right but just for demo would work is all i am saying

Comment: hi i am facing issues implementing this demo..check this https://jsfiddle.net/8duv7yoj/17/  ...my locationChangeStart isn't firing

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `$location` module.
Inject module into your controller and on confirm set `$location.path(your path here)`

Look AngularJS documentation fore more information : [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: Hi I tried using the $location module inside my if statement but still it does not get directed to the path

Comment: I think you try to set path to location that didn't mapped in router

Comment: when i tried alerting the variable newUrl it gives me the entire URL path but the route is the part after the # ..so then do i need to parse it?